# Consider a sentence that is valid on all cyclic groups $Z_n$. Show it's valid on some infinite group.

Tags: logic, compactness, first-order-logic

Let $\phi$ a sentence that is valid on all cyclic groups $Z_n$.
Show that $\phi$ is valid on some infinite group.

I know that " if $Σ$ is satisfied in finite structures of arbitrarly large universe, then $Σ$ is satisfied in an infinite structure."

What I´m thinking is to let $Σ$ be the formula: ($\phi$ and "it's a group").
This way, $Σ$ is satisfied in an infinite structure, ie, there's an infinite group that satisfies  $\phi$.

Is this right?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your header is not the same as the body of your post.  $\mathbb Z$ is cyclic, but it is not of the form $\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: What do you mean by sentence? What if $\phi = \text{"I have finitely many elements"}?$

Comment: @Yanko "There are only finitely many elements" is not expressible in the first order language of groups.

Comment: Yeah I guess that is what he meant, but it is not written anywhere. Or maybe a "sentence" is the official term for "expressible in the first order language of groups"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Yes, what you have said seems correct. Upward Lowenheim-Skolem implies the desired result.

Here is another direct way to get the same result:

Take $\Sigma$ to include the group axioms along with $\phi$ and, for each $n$, a sentence $\psi_n$ asserting there are at least $n$ elements.

Each finite subset of this collection has a model. Since the subset is finite, there is a largest $n$ for which $\psi_n$ is in $\Sigma$. By assumption, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a model for these sentences. By compactness, the whole set has a model. But this model must be an infinite group satisfying $\phi$.

Comment: Would you the way I answered is correct?

Comment: @Albi , there is nothing in your $\Sigma$ that guarantees the final model is infinite. Also, your write up is a bit unclear. It doesn't seem like you apply compactness anywhere in the proof, which is a sign something is wrong.

Comment: I used a corolary of the compactness, which was: " if a formula Σ is satisfied in finite structures of arbitrarly large universe, then Σ is satisfied in an infinite structure.", and with Σ being the formula: (ϕ and "it's a group"). Doesn´t this garantee the inifinity and use of compactness?

Comment: @Albi Ah, I think I misunderstood your original post; you are using Upward Lowenheim-Skolem? If so, then yes, that sounds good.